# Relationship Handling: Hibernate vs JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jdbc

Imagine I have a MySQL database with the 2 tables `patient` and `medicine`. I have displayed their columns below.

**Patient**

```
idPatient (int) (primary key)
first_name (varchar)
last_name (varchar)
```

**Medicine**

```
idMedicine (int) (primary key)
idPatient (int) (foreign key)
drug_name (varchar)
```

Please note that `Medicine` table does have the foriegn key of `Patient` table.

Now, if I use pure JDBC, I will do the following to create a bean for the `Medicine` and `Patient` tables

**`PatientBean` class**

```
public class PatientBean
{
    private int idPatient;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

    public void setIdPatient(int idPatient)
    {
        this.idPatient = idPatient;
    }

    public int getIdPatient()
    {
        return idPatient;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first_name)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setLastName(String last_name)
    {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return last_name;
    }

}

`MedicineBean` class

public class MedicineBean
{
    private int idMedicine;
    private int idPatient;
    private String drug_name;

    public void setIdMedicine(int idMedicine)
    {
        this.idMedicine = idMedicine;
    }

    public int getIdMedicine()
    {
        return idMedicine;
    }

    public void setIdPatient(int idPatient)
    {
        this.idPatient = idPatient;
    }

    public int getIdPatient()
    {
        return idPatient;
    }

    public void setDrugName(String drug_name)
    {
        this.drug_name = drug_name;
    }

    public String getDrugName()
    {
        return drug_name;
    }

}
```

However if I reverse engineer my database for hibernate using a tool like NetBeans which will generate the POJO files, mapping etc for Hibernate, I can expect something like below.

**`PatientBean` class**

```
public class PatientBean
    {
        private int idPatient;
        private String first_name;
        private String last_name;
    private MedicineBean medicineBean;

        public void setIdPatient(int idPatient)
        {
            this.idPatient = idPatient;
        }

        public int getIdPatient()
        {
            return idPatient;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String first_name)
        {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return first_name;
        }

        public void setLastName(String last_name)
        {
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return last_name;
        }

    public void setMedicineBean(String medicineBean)
        {
            this.medicineBean = medicineBean;
        }

        public String getMedicineBean()
        {
            return medicineBean;
        }
    }
```

**`MedicineBean` class**

```
public class MedicineBean
    {
        private int idMedicine;
        private int idPatient;
        private String drug_name;
    private Set<PatientBean> patients = new HashSet<PatientBean>(0);

        public void setIdMedicine(int idMedicine)
        {
            this.idMedicine = idMedicine;
        }

        public int getIdMedicine()
        {
            return idMedicine;
        }

        public void setIdPatient(int idPatient)
        {
            this.idPatient = idPatient;
        }

        public int getIdPatient()
        {
            return idPatient;
        }

        public void setDrugName(String drug_name)
        {
            this.drug_name = drug_name;
        }

        public String getDrugName()
        {
            return drug_name;
        }

    public void setPatients(Set<PatientBean>patients)
    {
        this.patients = patients;
    }

    public Set<PatientBean> getPatients()
    {
        return patients;
    }

    }
```

Not only this, Hibernate will also map the relationship type (one to one, one to many, many to one) inside the xml files. However in JDBC we don't care about them at all, they are just foreign keys treated in same way.

So my question is, why is this difference? I believe most of the operations Hibernate does are useless and just using CPU. For an example, trying to retrieve the list of `patients` in `Patient` table when we call `getAllMedicines()` method. In 99% of the case we just need all medicines not the list of patients, if we need that we can make a join and get it!

So what is the reason behind this? Or else should we maintain the same behavior for JDBC too?

Comment: The `patient` list will usually be lazy loaded, meaning that it will only read the Data if needed.  The second way contains your data as you would normally write it in a OO program

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Yes I know. My question is why we don't do the same in JDBC? I see it simply useless.

Comment: The only reason you're not doing it in JDBC, is because *you* are not doing it in JDBC. *You* are in full control of exactly how you want to do it, so you could do it by replacing MedicineBean's `int idPatient` with `PatientBean patient`, and adding a `List<MedicineBean> medicines` to PatientBean. Depending on exactly how they are used, that's another way to do it.

Comment: @Andreas: There we go.. Using `Hibernate` is causing serious issues in my REST API with `failed to lazily initialize collection` errors because of this unwanted attempt of loading other stuff. I tried everything in JBOSS site advice for Hibernate, no use at all. I prefer to have `int idPatient` in `MedicineBean` instead of `PatientBean patient` because I can always use a join if needed.

Comment: @Andreas: Requesting an advice on this, I really need total control of what I do, so JDBC is better?

Comment: "Better" is a matter of opinion, but if you use JDBC directly, you're definitely in full control of exactly what SQL statements are sent to the database. How much better that is, depends in part on your SQL skills.

Comment: You can always choose to  use a lightweight O/RM library instead of Hibernate. This way, you still get the power and flexibility of O/RM without the overhead (and what not else) of Hibernate.

Comment: @Andreas: My SQL skills are in maximum level as I have even done Big Data with pure MySQL

Comment: @dsp_user: Please advice suggestions

Comment: Well, SQLite has been around for quite a while. I've also written a small O/RM library (some examples are available at http://easyorm.info ).

Comment: @dsp_user: SQLite is a database?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Ormlite (http://ormlite.com/).

Comment: If you want to have a lightweight `O/RM`, consider `iBatis` as it gives you the flexibility to use your native SQL queries, stored procedures and etc.!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that with hibernate you lose the full control as you are afraid.

The main difference is that hibernate will add an extra layer between your code and jdbc. This layer can be really thin : you have the choice to use jdbc in hibernate **at anytime**. So you are not losing any control.

The harder part is to understand how hibernate works so that you can use its higher level api and know how hibernate will translate that to jdbc. This is a bit a complex task, because orm mapping is a complex subject. Reading several times the reference documentation, to know exactly what hibernate can do, and what they recommend to do and not do, is a good starting point. The remaining will come from experience using hibernate.

For your example, you say hibernate map relationship, but this is not the case : your reverse-engineering tool did it. You are free to not map a relationship and map instead just the foreign key basic type (like a Long if the id is a number).

As for the loading of stuff. If you wish to always have a @OneToMany loaded, just annotate it with `FetchType.EAGER`. `@*ToMany` associations are lazy by default (to avoid loading too many data), but on the other hand, `@*ToOne` assocation are `EAGER` by default.

This can be configured at the entity level, making it the default behavior for queries, but can be overloaded for each query.

You see ? You are not losing control, you just need to understand how the hibernate api translate to jdbc.

Apart from bugs, which are fixed when raised to the hibernate team, the performance impact of hibernate is not that much. And in performance critical part of the application, you always have the choice to resort to jdbc, where the hibernate overhead is 0.

What do you gain from using hibernate ? From my experience, refactoring in entity model / database model is much easier, because you change the hibernate mapping, and all the queries generated by hibernate are automatically changed too. You just have to update the custom queries (SQL / HQL / Criteria) that you've hand-written.

From my experience (10 years using hibernate) on a several hundred tables (some of them with more than 10B rows), several terabytes database, i would not want to go back to plain jdbc, which does not mean i don't use it when it is the perfect tool, but it is just like 1 or 2% of the orm code i write.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: and if you are using hibernate with spring, have a look at spring-jdbc which adds a nice layer around jdbc. There, you nearly doesn't need to read the doc: you recognize directly how it will be translated to jdbc, but it brings lots of utility that reduce a lot the boilerplate of using jdbc directly (like exception handling to close `Resultset` and `PreparedStatement`, transformation of `ResultSet` to List of DTO, etc.).

Of course hibernate and spring-jdbc can be used in the same application. They just have to be configured to use the same transaction layer, and care be taken when used in the same tx.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. No I don't use Hibernate with Spring, I am building a `REST API`. I can't agree with you here - `If you wish to always have a @OneToMany loaded, just annotate it with FetchType.EAGER` which will be a huge overhead.` Anyway, you mean I can use foreign keys like `idPatient` simply as that in Hibernate without making it a `SET` or a complete bean? Then I have to change the associated XML isn't it? I'm not using annotations.

Comment: That i said stands also for hbm mappings. Why do you say it is a huge overhead ? To load the parent entity, hibernate will trigger 2 queries : one to load the parent (by id, one row, should not be heavy), one for the child collection which you are interested in. You don't need the parent entity ? just create a Criteria / HQL / SQL to load the child entities where parent_id = parent.id (and do not forget to mark the ManyToOne as LAZY). The hbm mapping files needs to reflect two things : the database model, and how you wish to access entities from java code. FYI, hbm files have been deprecated.

Comment: I answered your question from a high level standpoint because it seemed to me that you wanted more a global insight than an answer on a precise part of hibernate. If this in not the case, please add to your question the database model of your tables, and the hbm mapping files, the sql queries you expected hibernate to generate, and your hibernate loading code, and we'll see how we can modify the mapping and hibernate code to get what you wish.

Comment: Thanks. My question is very related to the question by my colleague here, we are facing it now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637121/hibernate-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-beans-language-pati

Comment: I can re-post it if he has not made that post clear enough.

Comment: no no the question is clear... but this a a complex interaction between your json converter and hibernate. Give me a bit of time to write an anwser there ;)